# Copy only 1 property of an object from an Array of objects to a new Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects like this:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Bill',
    age: 42
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Jack',
    age: 37
  }
]
```

I know how to copy all of it to the new array by using array spreads `...` in es6 instead of `slice()`

```
const newArray = [...oldArray];
```

I just want to extract the name using the method below:

```
const newArray = [];
for (i = 0; i < oldArray.length; i++) {
    newArray.push(oldArray[i].name);
}
```

Is there a better method to do this in es6?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
let people = 
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Bill',
    age: 42
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Jack',
    age: 37
  }
]

let names = people.map(person => person.name)
```

[jsbin](https://jsbin.com/ziqurijuqa/edit?html,js,console,output).

Comment: ES5 version `people.map(function(p){ return p.name})`